# Creating a bulleted list of variable length using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project where I need to put items from my controller into a bulleted list. Some of these items might have a null value, in which case I do not want a bullet to appear. Currently, the code doesn't support this. Here's the obviously nonfunctional html:

```
<ul>
    <li>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Use)</li>
    <li>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Gtype)</li>
    <li>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Notes)</li>
</ul>
```

So if item.Notes is empty, there will still be a bullet. Is there a solution to this that doesn't involve js? I'm pretty new to .net and have had some trouble implementing js-based solutions to problems.

Comment: Do an If condition to check `null` before the `li` rendering code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a method to `itemModel` that determines if the `itemModel` has a value, then wrap `<li>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Notes)</li>` in `@if (item.Notes.HasValue()) {}`.